# How can the quantisation of the energy of an oscillator be derived from the concept of entropy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, entropy, harmonic-oscillator

In quantum mechanics the energy of the harmonic oscillator is quantised, which means it can only take on discrete energy levels. In an equation:
$$ E_n = nhf$$

Planck did a lot of research on entropy. How can it clearly be shown that the discrete energy levels is a natural consequence of the entropy principle (if it can be shown at all?)

Answer (score 2):

With the assumption $E=nhf$, the distribution of states that maximizes the thermodynamic entropy for blackbody radiation is the [Planck spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law), which is in excellent agreement with many observations.

Assuming purely classical electromagnetism, the distribution of states that maximizes the entropy is the [Rayleigh-Jeans spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Jeans_law), which (a) is unphysical because it diverges at high energies (leading to, eg, an infinite average frequency for the radiation), and (b) does not agree with experiment.

You can learn more by reading about [black body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation). At the undergraduate level, this is covered in courses on modern physics, for which there are many good books.